IntelliJ Idea - how to go back to Diff tab?

Open a "Diff tab" (a tab, which shows differences between two files or versions or whatever). For example by selecting two files in Project Tool Window and select Compare files
Open another file.
Try to go back to the "Diff tab" by Recent Files (Ctrl + E by default) or by Switcher (Ctrl + Tab by default) - the "Diff tab" is not there

Is there any option how to add it into the Recent Files or Switcher?
I can get Diff tab by "go back" (Alt + left), but it is not an option because I do not want to press it many times till I get it.

Which ide version are you using? It should be available in both those menus. Can you share some examples?

I've created an issue

It's currently a bug in IntelliJ
